# Challenge to calculate maximum quantity and split sets with PHP

Tags: php, set

I have two items, A and B. You can only have a maximum set of 2 items at any one time. This results in the following combinations:

```
A B
1 0
2 0
0 1
0 2
1 1
```

If you want 3 or more items, the remainders spill over into a new set. Sets of 2 are preferred over single items in a set. Examples:

- 2 lots of A and 1 lot of B (total 3 items) would be 2 sets: 2 0, 0 1 OR 1 1, 1 0
- 3 lots of A and 4 lots of B (total 7 items) would be 4 sets: 2 0, 1 0, 0 2, 0 2 OR 1 1, 1 1, 1 1, 0 1...

What PHP code would be most efficient to calculate:

- Combinations in each set
- Total number of sets
- All variations of sets

**Sample:**

```
//input
$a = 2;
$b = 1;
$totalItems = $a + $b;
$totalSets = ceil($totalItems/2);
$maxPerSet = 2;

//split into sets of $maxPerSet
for($i = 0; $i < $totalSets; $i ++) {
    //calculate combinations of $a and $b
    //? code goes here...
    if($a >= $maxPerSet){
        $setA = $maxPerSet;  $setB = 0;  $a = $a - $maxPerSet;

    } else if($b >= $maxPerSet){
        $setB = $maxPerSet;  $setA = 0;  $b = $b - $maxPerSet;

    } else {
        if($a + $b > $maxPerSet){
            $setA = $a;
            $setB = $b - ($a-$maxPerSet); //not right!
            $a = 0;
        } else {
            $setA = $a;  $a = 0;  $setB = $b;  $b = 0;
        }
    }

    //add to array of sets
    $sets[$i] = "$setA $setB";
}

//ouput
print_r $sets;
```

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to see what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Can you clarify and/or provided sample input and desired output?

Comment: Maybe you need to clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

These are some considerations about finding all combinations:

First find all combinations to achive the larger of the two categories (A or B) by 1 or 2 items; it shall be easy to calculate the possible amounts of 1s and 2s and then to enumerate their positions (combinations **I**).

10 = 2+2+2+2+2 or 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1 or 2+2+2+1+1+1+1

Then you can add the other categorie's amount. Each set of 2 is already full, each set of 1 may or may not get another one attached. Having all such combinations **II** (2 for each set of 1), you can calculate how many of the smaller category are missing. Eliminate such combinations **II** that include too many of the second category.

Finally the amount of missing items in each combination *II* must be filled up - using 0/1 or 0/2 sets. This is the same problem as above. Due to smaller amounts, caching may increase performance here. So for each combination **II** you enumerate by the combinations for the missing items and finally have the combinations *III* you were looking for.

Together:

1. Possible amounts of 1 (1/0) and 2 (2/0)-sets to achive the larger categorie's (e.g. A's) amount
   I. Systematic shuffling of the 1/0s and 2/0s
   II. Two possible combinations for each 1/0 -> 1/0 or 1/1 - and elimination of impossible combinations II
   III. Possible combinations for the missing amount of (e.g.) B's like in I

However, solving puzzles has not a lot to do with PHP. And regarding performance it depends a lot on the system on the amounts. Caching may increase performance for some combinations and decrease for others. And of course the algorith suggestes above has a lot of room for optimizations.